# Unexpected type of values when using `df.loc`

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given a pandas DataFrame as follows

```py
# python 3.8.2
import pandas as pd # 1.0.5

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [0.5], 'y': [1]})
```

When I check types of two columns, they are float64 and int64 as expected.

```py
print(df.dtypes)
# x    float64
# y      int64
# dtype: object
```

However, when extracting the value of `y` column in a row, I got two different types depending on how I use `df.loc`.

```
#1
_, y_val = df.loc[0, ['x', 'y']]
print(type(y_val)) # <class 'float'>, it is unexpected

#2
y_val = df.loc[0, 'y']
print(type(y_val)) # <class 'numpy.int64'>
```

I believe `x` column in the DataFrame causes the difference, but I don't know why. In addition, is it possible to use the #1 syntax and acquire `y` values as integers?

Any help would be welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `df.loc[0, ['x', 'y']]` returns a series, hence it converts column y to a float since x is a float.

Answer (score 1):

`loc` returns a Pandas series object when you select a row. When the series has a mix of types (`int` and `float` in this case) all the integer numbers are casted to float.

I guess the simplest solution is just to cast `y_val` to `int`:

```py
_, y_val = df.loc[0, ['x', 'y']]
y_val = int(y_val)
```

Or you could select only the ***y*** column, so that you would get an integer directly:

```py
y_val = df.loc[0, "y"]
```